# How to calculate stock's daily returns in R using data.frame?

Tags: r, finance

**(daily return percentage) / 100 = (today's close - yesterday's close) / yesterday's close**

I have a data frame like this,

```
         date    close
1  2018-09-21 3410.486
2  2018-09-20 3310.126
3  2018-09-19 3312.482
4  2018-09-18 3269.432
5  2018-09-17 3204.922
6  2018-09-14 3242.090
7  2018-09-13 3236.566
8  2018-09-12 3202.025
9  2018-09-11 3224.212
10 2018-09-10 3230.068
11 2018-09-07 3277.644
12 2018-09-06 3262.881
13 2018-09-05 3298.141
14 2018-09-04 3363.898
15 2018-09-03 3321.825
```

I'd like to calculate daily returns and make it like this,

```
         date    close  change
1  2018-09-21 3410.486  3.0319
2  2018-09-20 3310.126 -0.0711
3  2018-09-19 3312.482  1.3168
4  2018-09-18 3269.432  2.0128
5  2018-09-17 3204.922 -1.1464
6  2018-09-14 3242.090  0.1707
7  2018-09-13 3236.566  1.0787
8  2018-09-12 3202.025 -0.6881
9  2018-09-11 3224.212 -0.1813
10 2018-09-10 3230.068 -1.4515
11 2018-09-07 3277.644  0.4525
12 2018-09-06 3262.881 -1.0691
13 2018-09-05 3298.141 -1.9548
14 2018-09-04 3363.898  1.2666
15 2018-09-03 3321.825      NA
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please consider editing your answer to include the code you've written while attempting your own solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option

```
df$change <- c(-diff(df$close)/df$close[-1] *  100, NA)

df
#         date    close      change
#1  2018-09-21 3410.486  3.03190876
#2  2018-09-20 3310.126 -0.07112491
#3  2018-09-19 3312.482  1.31674248
#4  2018-09-18 3269.432  2.01284150
#5  2018-09-17 3204.922 -1.14642098
#6  2018-09-14 3242.090  0.17067472
#7  2018-09-13 3236.566  1.07872362
#8  2018-09-12 3202.025 -0.68813713
#9  2018-09-11 3224.212 -0.18129649
#10 2018-09-10 3230.068 -1.45153043
#11 2018-09-07 3277.644  0.45245291
#12 2018-09-06 3262.881 -1.06908710
#13 2018-09-05 3298.141 -1.95478579
#14 2018-09-04 3363.898  1.26656281
#15 2018-09-03 3321.825          NA
```

We use `diff` to get lagged differences of `close` and then divide it by `close` ignoring the first row and add a `NA` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `lag` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)

close_yesterday <- lag.zoo(df$close, 1, na.pad=TRUE)
df$change <- 100.0 * (df$close - close_yesterday) / close_yesterday
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all dates are consecutive days, the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)

# based on your formula    
df %>% mutate(change = (close - lead(close)) / lead(close))

# based on your outcome 
df %>% mutate(change = (close - lead(close)) / lead(close) * 100)
```